# While loop not stopping when 2D array cell isn't defined (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, while-loop, do-while

**Goal:** Run through the columns of a 2D array (comes from an Excel file with uneven column lengths) and put the entries that exist into their own array.

**What I did:** The length of the longest column is 90 entries, which is the second column in the Excel file, and the shortest is 30, which is the first column. I set up a `for` loop to go through each column and a `while` loop to go through each entry while it exists and append it to a new array.

**Original(ish) Code:**

```js
    //read in Excel file into 2D array called "myExcel"

    var columnNames = ["shortest", "longest", "irrelevant"];

    shortArray = [];
    longArray = [];
    irrArray = [];
    var s

    for (var i = 0; i < columnNames.length; i++) {        
      var columnName = columnNames[i];
      s = 0;

      while (myExcel[s][columnName]) {

        if ((columnName === "shortest")) {
          var row = myExcel[s][columnName];
          shortArray.append(row);            
          s++;

        } else if ((columnName === "longest")) {
          var row = myExcel[s][columnName];
          longArray.append(row);            
          s++;

        } else if ((columnName === "irrelevant")) {
          var row = myExcel[s][columnName];
          irrArray.append(row);            
          s++;
        }
      }
    }
```

**Problem:** It's only half working. It makes it through the first column (30 rows) just fine--it stops when `myExcel[s][columnName]` no longer exists (when `columnName = "shortest"` and after `s = 29`). Then, it makes it all the way through `columnName = "longest"` and `s = 89` before giving me the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'longest' of undefined". I'm assuming it's because it's trying to go through row 90, which doesn't exist. But I thought that's where my while loop would stop.

**What I've Tried:**

*do while loop*

```js
    //blah

      do {

        //blah

      } while (myExcel[s][columnName]);
```

*Added additional while loop condition*

```js
    //blah

      while ((myExcel[s][columnName]) && s<myExcel.length) {

        //blah

      }
```

*Using typeof*

```js
    //blah

      while (typeof (myExcel[s][columnName]) === 'string') { //also used this with !=='undefined' and ==='string' when I added a number to the end of each row in the Excel sheet

        //blah

      }
```

And basically every combination of these (and probably much more I'm forgetting). I'm sure it's an easy fix, but I've spent days trying to figure it out so I guess I have to ask for help at this point. I'm also a MATLAB person and recently had to learn both Python and Javascript because of COVID, so it could possibly be a language switch issue (although I don't think so because I've been googling and messing with this for days). Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Update: I added `console.log(myExcel[s][columnName], s);` after the while loop & before the if/else statements & again after the if/else statements, but still in the while loop (labeled "before" & "after" in console). So I get `before: glasses 0; after: paper 1; before: paper 1` and so on. Before it freezes, it has `before: river 88; after: mushroom 89; before: mushroom 89`. So it does make it to the beginning of the last while loop and knows that the word exists, but has a problem when it gets to `if columnName === "longest"`, even though it hadn't before this last run through. @Thomas @Fasid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your while loop change the check to,

```
while(myExcel[s] && myExcel[s][columnName] ) {
```

If you are writing modern Js, then you could simply optional chain it like so, `while(myExcel[s]?.[columnName])`

The thing is, you are trying to traverse inside an outer array. But you first need to check if outer array exists and then go check the inner array.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, it's still stopping at the same point. :( Is there something else that could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand you approach, but I think you're looking for this:

```
var shortArray = [];
var longArray = [];
var irrArray = [];

for(let row of myExcel){
  if(!row) continue; // not sure if this check is necessary.
  if(row.shortest) shortArray.append(row.shortest);
  if(row.longest) longArray.append(row.longest);
  if(row.irrelevant) irrArray.append(row.irrelevant);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I was honestly just trying to figure out how to translate my python code, which is why the method might be weird. Is writing ".columnName" how you call to columns automatically or do I have to define that at some point?